# gcli.addCommandでTypeErrorが出て実行できない

Tags: javascript, firefox

MDNの記事を参考にfirefoxでスクラッチパッドを用いてGCLIコマンドを作成しようとしたのですがgcli.addCommand　でTypeErrorが出てしまいGCLIコマンド作成の前にコマンドが登録出来ません。

gcli　オブジェクトは読み込めているようです。

読み込まれているgcliのプロパティはhiddenByChromePredだけなので、うまく読み込まれていないのでしょうか。

resource://gre/modules/devtools/gcli/
上記のディレクトリにはファイルはしっかりあるようです。

実際にスクラッチパッドで実行しているソースコードは下記です。

```
Components.utils.import("resource://gre/modules/devtools/gcli.jsm");

gcli.addCommand({
  name: 'hello',
  description: 'Show a message',
  params: [
    {
      name: 'name',
      type: 'string',
      description: 'Who to say hello to',
    }
  ],
  exec: function(args, context) {
    return 'Good morning, ' + args.name;
  }
});
```

エラーは下記が表示が表示されました。

```
    /*
Exception: TypeError: gcli.addCommand is not a function
@Scratchpad/2:3:1
WCA_evalWithDebugger@resource://gre/modules/commonjs/toolkit/loader.js -> resource://gre/modules/devtools/server/actors/webconsole.js:1195:16
WCA_onEvaluateJS@resource://gre/modules/commonjs/toolkit/loader.js -> resource://gre/modules/devtools/server/actors/webconsole.js:811:20
WCA_onEvaluateJSAsync@resource://gre/modules/commonjs/toolkit/loader.js -> resource://gre/modules/devtools/server/actors/webconsole.js:782:20
DSC_onPacket@resource://gre/modules/commonjs/toolkit/loader.js -> resource://gre/modules/devtools/server/main.js:1586:15
LocalDebuggerTransport.prototype.send/<@resource://gre/modules/devtools/dbg-client.jsm -> resource://gre/modules/devtools/transport/transport.js:569:11
makeInfallible/<@resource://gre/modules/commonjs/toolkit/loader.js -> resource://gre/modules/devtools/DevToolsUtils.js:83:14
makeInfallible/<@resource://gre/modules/commonjs/toolkit/loader.js -> resource://gre/modules/devtools/DevToolsUtils.js:83:14
*/
```

firefoxのバージョンは42.0です。
スクラッチパッドの実行環境も’ブラウザ’を選択しています。

参考にした記事：
https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Tools/GCLI/Scratchpad

ご教授いただけましたら幸いです。よろしくお願いします。